# How do include something if no defines are found

Tags: delphi, uses-clause

I use the following code in my settings classes to determine what to use.
But now I have run in to the problem that I had forgotten to copy the correct .INC file to my project folder and that give me an AV since none of the defines are found.
How do I make sure that if none of the defines are found then U_SettingsConnIni are always in the uses section

```
 uses
  Dialogs, Forms, SysUtils,
{$IFDEF SETTINGSINI}
  U_SettingsConnIni,
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF SETTINGSREG}
  U_SettingsConnReg,
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF SETTINGSXML}
  U_SettingsConnXml,
{$ENDIF}
  U_SectionNames;
```

Comment: If only one define will be specified at a time, use [`IF..ELSE`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/IF_directive_(Delphi)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a scenario better suited to the more powerful [`$IF`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/IF_directive_%28Delphi%29) than the rather limited `$IFDEF`.

```
uses
  Dialogs, Forms, SysUtils,
{$IF Defined(SETTINGSREG)}
  U_SettingsConnReg,
{$ELSEIF Defined(SETTINGSXML)}
  U_SettingsConnXml,
{$ELSE}
  U_SettingsConnIni,
{$IFEND}
  U_SectionNames;
```

In the latest versions of Delphi you can use `$ENDIF` here rather than `$IFEND` if you prefer.

If you want to fail if no conditional is defined, you can do this:

```
uses
  Dialogs, Forms, SysUtils,
{$IF Defined(SETTINGSREG)}
  U_SettingsConnReg,
{$ELSEIF Defined(SETTINGSXML)}
  U_SettingsConnXml,
{$ELSEIF Defined(SETTINGSINI)}
  U_SettingsConnIni,
{$ELSE}
  {$Message Fatal 'Settings file format conditional must be defined'}
{$IFEND}
  U_SectionNames;
```

Comment: Hefferman   am I right to assume that your solution eliminates the need for the code by Jan Doggen?

Comment: I'll update the answer to show how to force at least one define.

Answer (score 3):

Just like ordinary `if` blocks, `$ifdef` compiler directives support [`$else`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/ELSE_%28Delphi%29). Furthermore, they can be nested.

```
uses
  Dialogs, Forms, SysUtils,
{$IFDEF SETTINGSREG}
  U_SettingsConnReg,
{$ELSE}
  {$IFDEF SETTINGSXML}
  U_SettingsConnXml,
  {$ELSE}
  U_SettingsConnIni,
  {$ENDIF}
{$ENDIF}
  U_SectionNames;
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method (not exactly answering your question), if you know that one of the defines **is** required, is to make sure that the compilation fails. In your case that would be:

```
{$IFNDEF SETTINGSINI}
{$IFNDEF SETTINGSREG}
{$IFNDEF SETTINGSXML}
This line does not compile
{$ENDIF}
{$ENDIF}
{$ENDIF}
```

That way if none of the conditional defines is set, the compiler will choke on `This line does not compile`.

Comment: that should have been my next question - how to check if none of the defines have been set.